# References for Teichmüller space of pointed elliptic curves

Tags: reference-request, teichmuller-theory

Where can I find an elementary introduction (construction, description, main properties) to the Teichmüller space ${\cal T}_{1,n}$ of elliptic curves with $n$-marked points?

Same question for the following associated objects: mapping class group $\Gamma_{1,n}$ and moduli space ${\cal M}_{1,n}={\cal T}_{1,n}/\Gamma_{1,n}$.

Thanks in advance for any reference.

Comment: It is the same in genus 1 as for the arbitrary genus. Any book with words 'Teichmuller theory' in the title would work.

Comment: Because  elliptic curves have explicit uniformizations, I was expecting that ${\cal T}_{1,n}$ can be described quite concretely...

Comment: Elliptic curves yes, but not the ones with punctures.

Comment: A recent related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/162690/nielsen-thurston-classification-of-homeomorphisms-for-open-surfaces/162699#162699

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On these questions, the following reference could be helpful:

S. NAG, *The torelli spaces of punctured tori and spheres*
Duke Math. Journal 48 (1981), p. 359-388.

http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.dmj/1077314655